# Always display the Rating bubble in md-slider

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

I'm going through [md-slider](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.slider) in `md-discrete` mode.
However, I want to display the slider bubble all the time like this:

[image]

I dont want this bubble to disappear when I click anywhere else. 
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it by overriding some css rules, by default the bubbles will be displayed only during active/focus states via below rule:

```
md-slider[md-discrete]:not([disabled]):focus .md-sign,
md-slider[md-discrete]:not([disabled]):focus .md-sign:after,
md-slider[md-discrete]:not([disabled]).active .md-sign,
md-slider[md-discrete]:not([disabled]).active .md-sign:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
}
```

So you can just override by making an absolute rule to display it always. i.e:

```
md-slider[md-discrete] .md-sign,
md-slider[md-discrete] .md-sign:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOygWE)**

Comment: the demo link you have provided does not show the bubble always as question asked. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcut way can be by using `onblur="this.focus()"` like this:

```
<md-slider id="my-slider" flex onblur="this.focus()" md-discrete ng-model="3" min="1" max="5" aria-label="rating">
```

And inside javascript do:

```
$("#my-slider").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me. The only thing that worked for me is adding the css class "_md-active" to the slider.

```
document.getElementById("YOUR-MD-SLIDER-ID").className += " _md-active";
```

Answer (score 0):

md-slider contain 2 part: md-track-container and md-thumb-container.
You can modify the part you need by css.
Here is the image to show and the code also.

> 

```
<md-slider title="md-title" style="margin-top: -31px;margin-left: 45px;" id="red-slider" md-discrete="" round="0" ng-model="" step="5" min="0" max="100" aria-label="rating" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuenow="55" aria-invalid="false" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
<div class="md-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="md-track-container">
        <div class="md-track"></div>
        <div class="md-track md-track-fill" style="width: 55%;"></div>
        <div class="md-track-ticks"><canvas style="position:absolute;" width="151" height="5"></canvas> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-thumb-container" style="left: 55%;">
        <div class="md-thumb"></div>
        <div class="md-focus-thumb"></div>
        <div class="md-focus-ring"></div>
        <div class="md-sign"><span class="md-thumb-text">55</span></div><div class="md-disabled-thumb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</md-slider>
```

CSS:

```
md-slider[md-discrete] .md-track-container,
md-slider[md-discrete] .md-track-container:after {
  height: 5px;
}

md-slider[md-discrete] .md-track-ticks,
md-slider[md-discrete] .md-track-ticks:after {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To show the bubble always**

```
.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
}
```

**For the text to appear**

```
.mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

**Changing the color of the thumbs**

```
.mat-slider-min-value.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing .mat-slider-thumb, 
.mat-slider-min-value.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Changing the color of the fill**

```
.mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill, .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb, .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    background-color: $greenColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 !important;
  }  
  .mat-slider-thumb {
    transform: scale(0) !important;
  }  
  .mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

This solution came from michaelpwilson here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4803